# How to write a regression equation with mediation?

Tags: regression, causality, mediation

For my master's thesis I am examining a mediated relationship. I need to write out the equation model, but do not know exactly how to do this. In my case I have four independent variables, one mediated variable and one dependent variable. How do I add the mediated variable to the equation? Until now I got this:

Exploitative innovation $= \alpha + \beta_1\ $Inspirational motivation $+\ \beta_2\  $ Individual consideration $ +\ \beta_3\ $ Intellectual stimulation $+\ \beta_4\ $  Idealized influence $+\ \beta_5$ Knowledge exchange and combination capabilities $+\ \epsilon, \epsilon \sim$ iin (0, $\sigma$).

$\beta_5$ is my mediated variable. Can I just add this or do I have to multiply something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not an expert on this, but the [Statistical Mediation Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediation_%28statistics%29) uses three regressions. In them, you would use an interaction (multiplication).

You might also look into [Structural Equation Modeling (SEM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_equation_modeling), which I believe can directly model mediation. R, Stata, and other packages can do SEMs, though it seems to be a bit of an art to me.

Also be clear if you're looking for mediation or moderation (or moderated mediation).